# Copy values of a column between data frames depending on values of another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I got these two data frames:

```
a <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H')
b <- c(1,2,1,3,1,3,1,6)
c <- c('K','K','H','H','K','K','H','H')

frame1 <- data.frame(a,b,c)

a <- c('A','A','B','B','C','C','D','D','E','E','F','F','G','H','H')
d <- c(5,5,6,3,1,9,1,0,2,3,6,5,5,5,4)
e <- c('W','W','D','D','D','D','W','W','D','D','W','W','D','W','W')

frame2<- data.frame(a,d,e)
```

And now I want to include the column 'e' from 'frame2' into 'frame1' depending on the matching value in column 'a' of both data frames. Note: 'e' is the same for all rows with the same value in 'a'.

The result should look like this:

```
  a b c e
1 A 1 K W
2 B 2 K D
3 C 1 H D
4 D 3 H W
5 E 1 K D
6 F 3 K W
7 G 1 H D
8 H 6 H W
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: `merge(frame1, frame2, by = 'a')` and remove column `d` from this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `match` to *matching value in column 'a' of both data frames*:

```
frame1$e <- frame2$e[match(frame1$a, frame2$a)]
frame1
#  a b c e
#1 A 1 K W
#2 B 2 K D
#3 C 1 H D
#4 D 3 H W
#5 E 1 K D
#6 F 3 K W
#7 G 1 H D
#8 H 6 H W
```

or using `merge`:

```
merge(frame1, frame2[!duplicated(frame2$a), c("a", "e")], all.x=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can perform join operation on 'a' column of both dataframes and take those values only which are matched. you can do left join , and after that remove 'a' column from 2nd dataframe and also remove rest of the columns, which are'nt needed from 2nd dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

frame2 %>%
  distinct(a, e, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  right_join(frame1, by = 'a') %>%
  select(-d) %>%
  arrange(a)

#  a e b c
#1 A W 1 K
#2 B D 2 K
#3 C D 1 H
#4 D W 3 H
#5 E D 1 K
#6 F W 3 K
#7 G D 1 H
#8 H W 6 H
```